# How do I add an enchantment to any type of item using /entitydata?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The setup I have is a command that will test all item frames `@e[type=ItemFrame]` and if an item is placed into it, I want the item to receive an enchantment, **but** I want it to allow **any** item and use only one command. Is this an option?

Comment: How can you even enchant a 'time'?

Comment: was supposed to be 'item' sorry, fixed in post.

Comment: Your best bet is to bruteforce... Except: The problem with that is that you can't test for the item frame's contents, only the entity type (which obviously is `ItemFrame`).

Comment: I guess you can't. Even enchanting a specific Item in that way requires at least 3 commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the enchantment is fine to be on any item, a simple /entitydata will do. Note that any enchantments that were previously on the item will be erased.

```
/entitydata @e[type=ItemFrame] {Item:{tag:{ench:[{id:16,lvl:1}]}}}
```

Comment: Well no it will overwrite any enchantment of the same, such as if it's 16 lvl 50 it would replace the lvl 50 but other then that this worked for me.

Comment: @Kronogenics The entire `ench` tag is essentially deleted off of the old entity and replaced with the new `ench` tag. This happens because it's a list-type tag. It *appears* as though it only merges in this case, but that's incorrect. It's simply coincidence because you've specified the same enchantment type to replace.